# SSD Ultra M.2 Slot Type

Tags: ssd

I bought a desktop with ASROCK Z370 Pro4 motherboard.Now I would like to upgrade my storage but I don't know which SSD slot type (NVME/SATA) should I buy.

This is my motherboard.

[image]

This is the slot in that I want to add a new SSD.

[image]

Does this slot support the NVME M.2 SSD? Is there any recommended SSD for that slot?

Answer (score 1):

If it supports NVMe, yes. What SSD you should put in there, depends on your budget. You can go 990 pro although that would be a bit overkill since your mobo only supports PCIe gen 3. Since that limitation exists, you can also go WD Blue (if you want to go cheaper) or Kinston KC2500 (if you want a bit more high end SSD)